# How to output JSON from TCL

Tags: tcl

What is the best way to generate `JSON` output such as this one from `TCL`? What data structures would you recommend for creating the `TCL` data in, and what `JSON` libraries would you use (keep it as standard as possible please)?

```
{
    "return_block": {
        "error_text": "0",
        "party_response_list": {
            "party_561": {"num": 228},
            "party_5037": {"num": 98}
        },
        "app_response_list": {
            "app_8141": {"num": 228},
            "app_9009": {"num": 98}
        }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tcl's "standard library" called `tcllib` (that's an external set of packages but it's available for any sensible OS) [provides](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/toc.html) the `json` and `json::write` packages.

Comment: Thank you. For my example JSON, what data structures would you use to generate my JSON output?

Comment: @JDor, with `json::write`, it does not really matter as the package supposes you traverse your data structures yourself and serialize the necessary (keys and) values in a way you think fits for them.

Comment: Yeah, I'm struggling a bit with it. I have the data in arrays at the moment e.g. party_id(561) is 228 etc. Maybe I need to ask a new question how to use the json::write package.

Comment: `json::write object {*}[array get party_id]` is an approximation of what you supposedly need

Answer (score 4):

The current most recommended JSON library for Tcl is [`rl_json`](https://github.com/RubyLane/rl_json), which is well-documented, fast and powerful. It's been designed to be able to scale up to *very* large documents.

```
package require rl_json

# Simple write the value into a Tcl variable
set errTxt "0"

# Build a composite JSON value; perfect for iteration out of a DB…
set parties {}
json set parties "party_561" "num" 228
json set parties "party_5037" "num" 98

# Another example, this time with actual iteration…
set apps {}
foreach {id num} {app_8141 228 app_9009 98} {
    json set apps $id "num" $num
}

# Build the overall doc and print it; note the interpolations of strings and JSON sub-documents
puts [json template {
    {"return_block": {
        "error_text": "~S:errTxt",
        "party_response_list": "~J:parties",
        "app_response_list": "~J:apps"
    }}
}]
```

Note that you *need* to be explicit about what sorts of things you are doing in key places; the library doesn't try to guess what the types of things are. (Also, you could just use a big collection of `json set` calls, but that's messy.)

Comment: Thanks Donal, very useful

Comment: Hmm... I am getting an exception when I execute the above code: `No JSON value found
    while executing
"json set parties "party_561" "num" 228"` 

Until now I was creating a JSON object with `json template` but I was trying to use `json set` and I wasn't having much success, so I tried the above example.

Comment: I had a look at the test suite and fiddled around a little more—it works if `parties` is a string representing an empty object literal; i.e: `set parties "{}"` or `set parties {{}}`